# Python Requests POST missing Content-Length for specific URL

Tags: python, post, python-requests, content-type, content-length

I am trying to do a basic POST request using the Requests module, but the Content-Length is always missing so the server ignores the payload. My payload is a dict but Requests can't seem to calculate the Content-Length.

Here is my code:

```
form = {
'InternalApplicationSource' : 'signedinhome.recommendedjobs',
'__RequestVerificationToken' : str(rvt),
'Candidate.CVName' : 'CV.docx',
'JobTitle' : str(jtl),
'AppSource.AppSourceId' : '',
'AppSource.MatchCount' : '',
'IsExternalApplication' : 'False',
'Candidate.CoverLetterPreference' : 'None',
'Candidate.IsExternalApplication' : 'False',
'JobId' : str(jid),
'Source' : 'signedinhome.recommendedjobs',
'UserHasRegisteredThroughJob' : 'False'
}


post_headers = {
'Host': 'www.reed.co.uk',
'Origin' : 'https://www.reed.co.uk',
'User-Agent': browser,
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.7,jv;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'DNT': '1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'TE': 'Trailers'
}

post_headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Referer' : joburl , 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-Length':str(len(form))})
postres = session.post('https://www.reed.co.uk/api/application/apply',headers=post_headers,data=form)
```

And these are the headers that are actually sent (obtained from postres.request.headers)

```
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
Accept : */*
Connection : keep-alive
Host : www.reed.co.uk
Origin : https://www.reed.co.uk
Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.7,jv;q=0.3
DNT : 1
TE : Trailers
Referer : https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/
X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest
```

I have tried both setting the Content-Length (as above) and simply leaving Requests to calculate it, but that never happens, it is *always* missing from the headers sent.

I noticed that it also ommits the Content-Type header - does that mean this is an encoding issue?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

edit: I also noticed that this only happens with this specific URL, any other URL seems to be fine (content-length and type are all ok). I can only assume this is an issue with the requests module, as it concerns the data which is sent. Maybe the requests module checks the URL first and somehow acts differently for different URLs?

Comment: Try adding a header like 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' - not sure but you may also have to explicitly url encode and decode to binary.

Comment: But note you should remove the content-length header and requests should be adding it.

Comment: have you tried snooping on what your code is sending? There may be some other reason - have you done a GET on the session before doing the POST, to load up e.g. cookies? Try comparing what your code sends with what a browser sends doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I just noticed that this only happens with this specific URL, any other URL seems to be fine (content-length and type are all ok). I can only assume this is an issue with the requests module, as it concerns the data which is sent. Do you know if the requests module checks the URL first and somehow acts differently for different URLs?

Comment: Doesn’t seem likely to be a requests problem. But you could try asking on the requests github issues.

Comment: I’d check what’s actually sent on the wire, using e.g Telerik Fiddler or mitm

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It turns out my request was getting redirected, so what I was printing on screen was just the last request... when I used `allow_redirects=False`, I could finally see that actually both content-type and content-length were there, all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my request was getting redirected, so what I was printing on screen was just the last request... when I used `allow_redirects=False`, I could finally see my original POST request. And I could see that actually both Content-Type and Content-Length were there, all correct!